# How can I color in one zipcode in a map, RStudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, mapping, zipcode

I made a zipcode map of dallas using  this shapefile: https://gis.dallascityhall.com/shapefileDownload.aspx (Street Files)

```
dallas_streets %>% 
  sample_frac(1) %>% 
  group_by(POSTAL_L) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_convex_hull(st_union(geometry))) %>% 
  ggplot() + ggtitle("Zip Code Map of Dallas") +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = as.numeric(POSTAL_L))) + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = POSTAL_L)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "C") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: This is what I have right now]

I want to be able to have the map as greyscale and only one zipcode colored in, please let me know if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just add a column that specifies a key for the fill you want for each zipcode and then link it in the ggplot using `scale_fill_manual()`. Here, I do red for zip code 75241 and lightgray for all others.

```
dallas_streets2 <- dallas_streets %>% 
  sample_frac(1) %>% 
  group_by(POSTAL_L) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_convex_hull(st_union(geometry))) %>% 
  mutate(color = ifelse(POSTAL_L == "75241", "yes", "no"))

dallas_streets2 %>% 
  ggplot() + ggtitle("Zip Code Map of Dallas") +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = color)) + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = POSTAL_L)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "lightgray"), 
                    limits = c("yes", "no")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What if you change `scale_fill_vidris_c()` to `scale_fill_gray()` and then add `geom_sf(data=filter(dallas_streets, zip=='<zipcode>'), fill='#ff0000')` (where I arbitrarily chose red (`#ff0000`) as the color)? The combined code would look like:

```
ggplot(dallas_streets) + ggtitle("Zip Code Map of Dallas") +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = as.numeric(POSTAL_L))) + 
    scale_fill_gray()+
    geom_sf(data=filter(dallas_streets, zip=='<zipcode>'), fill='#ff0000')
    geom_sf_text(aes(label = POSTAL_L)) + 
    theme_minimal()
```