# how to color some specific counties using their FIP code on plot_usmap() in R

Tags: r, plot, fips

I wan to to color three counties 1001,1005,1007, is this possible via plot_usmap() function?

```
library(usmap)
plot_usmap(regions = "county", values = c(1001,1005,1007))
```

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547690/how-can-i-color-in-one-zipcode-in-a-map-rstudio/59547867#59547867

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I color in one zipcode in a map, RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547690/how-can-i-color-in-one-zipcode-in-a-map-rstudio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a dataset of all counties. Furtunately the usmap package has one "countypop", checking this we see, that the function input for the countycode is 5 digits as a character. We can use this information to make a new factor column, indicating wheather it is one of the desired/to be highlighted counties or not.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(usmap)

vec  <- c(1001,1005,01007)

dt <- countypop %>%
    dplyr::mutate(selected = factor(ifelse(fips %in% stringr::str_pad(vec, 5, pad = "0"), "1", "0")))
```

The second step is to use this generated dataset to build the map and fill the colors acording to the newly created variable:

```
usmap::plot_usmap(data = dt, values = "selected", color = "grey") +
    ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow"))
```

[image]

Comment: this is a clean, nice approach. but is there any other way to add 0 s before 4 digit county FIPs? this was, every time I do changes and run the code it adds a new 0 !

Comment: @Mathica I altered the answer to work with a input vector and add one or more 0 in case of any input having less then 5 digits

Comment: thank you. what do you think is my mistake when I use this vec <-   c(4013,  6037, 17031, 26163, 36059)? I get only two counties shaded as yellow, not five.

Comment: I justed tested it and the other 3 seem to be very small - please invert the order of colors and it should be clearer ... if that does not work, start a clean R session

Comment: a tick and useful answer sign is not even enough for your help! thanks for the time.