# Changing color of states in plot_usmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the color of states with status 3 and 4 in this map to gray with darker lines (as if they were not included). Is that possible?

```
library(usmap)

#data    
state <- datasets::state.name
    status <- rep(1:4)
    map <- cbind(state, status)
    map <- as.data.frame(map)
    map


#Map plot    
mapus <- plot_usmap(data = map, 
    values = "status", color = "white", 
    labels= TRUE, label_color = "black") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1", na.translate= FALSE,name = "X")+
    theme(legend.position = "top") + ggtitle("X")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68683905/12993861