# How do I fill certain counties on a US map in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to construct a map of the eastern US with the counties lying in Appalachia highlighted as a certain color, while non-Appalachian counties are left white. I have constructed a county map of the eastern US using the following code:

```r
library(usmap)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

us.counties = map_data('county')
head(us.counties)
#>        long      lat group order  region subregion
#> 1 -86.50517 32.34920     1     1 alabama   autauga
#> 2 -86.53382 32.35493     1     2 alabama   autauga
#> 3 -86.54527 32.36639     1     3 alabama   autauga
#> 4 -86.55673 32.37785     1     4 alabama   autauga
#> 5 -86.57966 32.38357     1     5 alabama   autauga
#> 6 -86.59111 32.37785     1     6 alabama   autauga

plot_usmap("counties", 
           include = c(.east_north_central, .east_south_central, .south_atlantic, 
                       .south_region, .northeast_region),
           exclude = c('TX', 'AR', 'LA', 'OK'))
```

Which returned this map showing the eastern US with counties outlined.

[image]

I also have the following data frame `appalachian.counties` containing a list of all US counties in Appalachia by name and state they are in.

```
> head(appalachian.counties)
   region subregion
1 alabama      bibb
2 alabama    blount
3 alabama   calhoun
4 alabama  chambers
5 alabama  cherokee
6 alabama   chilton
```

I would like to construct a map that looks like the blank map included above, but with the Appalachian counties included in the data frame `appalachian.counties` filled in a blue and the Appalachian counties specifically in Kentucky filled in red. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to shade different counties with different colors on US map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683058/how-to-shade-different-counties-with-different-colors-on-us-map-in-r/68683905#68683905)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
library(usmap)
library(maps)

us.counties = map_data('county')
states <- us.counties[us.counties$region %in% appalachian.counties$region,]

app <- us.counties[paste(us.counties$region, us.counties$subregion) %in%
 paste(appalachian.counties$region, appalachian.counties$subregion),]

ken <- app[app$region == "kentucky",]

ggplot(states, aes(long, lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "gray75") +
  geom_polygon(fill = "red", data = app, colour = "white") +
  geom_polygon(fill = "blue", data = ken, colour = "white") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]